# How to make a div stay at the top of the screen? After I scroll down it should stay in place and after i scroll up it goes down

Tags: javascript

> How do I make a div stay on the screen after scrolling down and it will stick to the top of the window and will follow the user as they scroll down... I tried the answers here but still it wont work... really need help...

The problem is here!!!

```
<div id="mainMenuBarAnchor"></div>
<div id="left_content" class="left_content">
  <ul class="left_menu">    
    <li class="odd"><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
    <li class="even"><a href="#">Size</a></li>
    <li class="odd"><a href="#">Color</a></li>
    <li class="even"><a href="#">Price</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the CSS [position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) property.
You'll also need to offset the body of the page by the height of the header so that nothing gets cut off on the initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

You shall do this with CSS as follows.

```
<style>
    #mainMenuBarAnchor {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 50%;
    }   
</style>
```

The div content will stay at top middle of the page regardless the user scroll. Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more detail.

Here is the complete html for your ease.

```
    <style>
        #mainMenuBarAnchor {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 50%;
        }   
    </style>    
    <div id="mainMenuBarAnchor">Top Anchor</div>
    <div id="left_content" class="left_content">
      <ul class="left_menu">    
        <li class="odd"><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="#">Size</a></li>
        <li class="odd"><a href="#">Color</a></li>
        <li class="even"><a href="#">Price</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```